# Merge fails with composite identifier containing association

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using hibernate to manage repository of midPoint, an open source identity management system. There are approximately 70 entities.

Recently we have come across an issue with merging entities that have composite identifiers containing associations.

The issue can be demonstrated on a really trivial example. It is almost directly derived from the [Hibernate 5.2 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations) (except for `OneToMany` side of the association).

Let us have a parent and a child entity:

**Parent.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", 
               orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    // getters, setters, equals, hashCode omitted for brevity
}
```

**Child.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    private String value;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashCode omitted for brevity
}
```

The scenario is:

1. Create a parent-child pair and persist it into the database.
2. Create a detached instance of the parent object that contains a new (transient) child instead of the original one.
3. Merge new instance of the parent object.

The code is like this (simplified):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create();
        update();
    }

    private static void create() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setId(10);

        Child child = new Child();
        child.setParent(parent);
        parent.getChildren().add(child);
        child.setValue("old");

        session.save(parent);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    private static void update() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setId(10);

        Child child = new Child();
        child.setParent(parent);
        parent.getChildren().add(child);
        child.setValue("new");

        session.merge(parent);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

And it fails because Hibernate tries to insert null values into the child table.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at simple.TestMergeParentChild.update(TestMergeParentChild.java:49)
    at simple.TestMergeParentChild.main(TestMergeParentChild.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3513)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "VALUE"; SQL statement:
/* insert simple.Child */ insert into Child (value, parent_id) values (?, ?) [23502-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:311)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:784)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 19 more
```

When looking at source code the problem seems to be here:

[Picture from the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdWr.png)

i.e. on [DefaultMergeEventListener:233](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2.12/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultMergeEventListener.java#L233) where `copyValues` method does not copy anything from the transient child entity into a newly created instance (perhaps because it omits the identifiers).

For me, it looks like a bug in Hibernate. But I am not experienced enough to know for sure. What I have tried to resolve that:

1. I replaced plain identifiers with `@IdClass` and/or `@EmbeddedId`. While this resolved the issue for [simple parent-child case](https://github.com/mederly/hibernate-test/tree/ed883405c718918ae1f5ed6e42d5e5cdbbee3f0a/src/main/java/simpleWithIdClass), it did not help for [more complex scenario](https://github.com/mederly/hibernate-test/tree/9ef0f4bb58065169c7e2b111b78215460e7d2991/src/main/java/testWithIdClass), more directly related to our midPoint usage.
2. The problem with more complex scenario is the `Unable to find column with logical name: owner_owner_oid in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(AssignmentExtension) and its related supertables and secondary tables` exception I get. When trying to resolve it using additional `@Column(..., insertable=false, updateable=false)` I get into yet another issues, besides the fact that the code becomes more and more uncomprehensive.
3. I tried to tell hibernate about the identifiers by using [@GeneratedValue annotations](https://github.com/mederly/hibernate-test/blob/9ef0f4bb58065169c7e2b111b78215460e7d2991/src/main/java/simpleWithIdentifierGenerators/Child.java), but it didn't help.
4. As a last resort I have tried to work around the code in `DefaultMergeEventListener` by persuading it that the transient entity has, in fact, an identifier. I used a [custom persister](https://github.com/mederly/hibernate-test/blob/ed883405c718918ae1f5ed6e42d5e5cdbbee3f0a/src/main/java/simpleWithCustomPersister/IdProvidingSingleTableEntityPersister.java) to do that. It helps (even in our application), but I am afraid of the ugliness of the solution; besides other things, it makes hibernate consider transient child instances to be detached, because now they do have an identifier (supplied by the application).

Please, how should I deal with the situation? Is this a hibernate bug that could be fixed in the future? Should I explore `@IdClass` way, trying to resolve issues that popped up there? I know that maybe the most natural way is introduce artificial (generated) IDs in the children tables but I'd like to avoid that because of the necessity to change DB schema.

Thank you a lot.

**Edit (2018-02-06)**: After [a discussion on discourse.hibernate.org](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/merge-fails-with-composite-identifier-containing-association/191) I have filed [HHH-12276](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12276). Alternative solution based on `@EmbeddedId` is yet to be verified.

Comment: Have someone verified the solution with @EmbeddedId since the bug still open?